# How to position JavaFX shapes within any Pane?

Tags: java, javafx, position

If I use a JavaFX element (for example, a `Circle`) directly in a `Scene` element it positions correctly. However, if I put it directly in a `Pane` (such as `BorderPane` below), then it isn't positioned right.

Example 1 (correctly positions Circle at (10,10)):

```
Circle c = new Circle(10,10,15);
Group g = new Group(c);
Scene s = new Scene(g,800,600);
stage.setScene(s);
stage.show();
```

Example 2 (doesn't work):

```
Circle c = new Circle(10,10,15);
Group g = new Group(c);
BorderPane b = new BorderPane();
b.setCenter(g);
Scene s = new Scene(b,800,600);
stage.setScene(s);
stage.show();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some panes handle the position of their children, regardless of what you set their `x` and `y` to, and some don't. If you want to set positions, you might want a `Pane` inside of a `BorderPane`.

From the API docs for Pane:

> This class may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of
>   children is required since it does not perform layout beyond resizing
>   resizable children to their preferred sizes. It is the application's
>   responsibility to position the children since the pane leaves the
>   positions alone during layout.

More here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html